# Prove $(3x^2+3) \geq (x+1)^2+1$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

$(3x^2+3) \geq (x+1)^2+1$

I tried using a direct proof but I think I got stumped along the way.

$3x^2+3 \geq x^2+2x+2$

$2x^2+1 \geq 2x$

$2(x^2) +1 \geq 2x$

$x^2 + (1/2) \geq x$

How can I make this appear more clear? I don't think this is evident that it is true.

Comment: Better to have everything on one side of the inequality, and compare with $0$: $x^2-x+(1/2)\ge0$. To prove this, complete the square.

Comment: The numbers will be nicer if we prove that $4x^2+1\ge 4x$, or equivalently that $4x*2-4x+2\ge 0$, that is, $(2x-1)^2+1\ge 0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try completing the square:
\begin{align*}
x^2 + 1/2 \geq x
&\iff x^2 - x + 1/2 \geq 0 \\
&\iff (x^2 - x + 1/4) - 1/4 + 1/2 \geq 0 \\
&\iff (x - 1/2)^2 + 1/4 \geq 0 \\
\end{align*}
which is always true for any $x \in \mathbb R$. So the original inequality must also always be true for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

For variety: let $f(x) = x^2 - x + 1/2$. Then $f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x = 1/2$, $f(1/2) = 1/4$, and $f''(x) = 2$ so that the function has a global minimum at $1/2$, where its value is positive. Hence $f \geq 0$ everywhere.